# Error printing from 16-bit applications in Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows, printing, windows-server-2008

I'm having problems trying to run a bunch of old 16-bit applications in Windows 2008 Server.
The applications ran fine up to Windows 2003 Server, but when I try to print from any of
them, all show printing errors (Unable to create printer driver / TERM error / etc)

- The LPT1 port is redirected to a shared printer via NET USE LPT1 \ServerName\SharedPrinter
- DIR > LPT1 (or any shell redirection to the printer) is working fine.
- I'm using an Administrator account, so it shouldn't be a permissions problem, right?

To reproduce the behavior, I made a small test program in C (TCC 1.01 for DOS). It runs fine
in XP / 2003 Server, but on 2008 Server it shows the handle opening (5) but when is trying
to write in that handle, issues an error (Write fault error writing device LPT1, Abort, Retry,
Ignore, Fail)

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>

int main(void)
{
 int handle, status;
 char* sbuff;

 handle = open("LPT1", O_WRONLY, S_IFBLK);
 printf("%d\n", handle);

 if (!handle)
 {
    printf("open failed\n");
    exit(1);
 }

 sbuff = "[print test]\n";
 write(handle, sbuff, strlen(sbuff));

 close(handle);
 getch();

 return 0;
}
```

Any clues?

TIA,
Pablo

Comment: Does your test program work correctly when compiled as 32-bit?

Comment: @Cameron: I didn't try it, but what should be the point of doing it? If it works I cannot recompile all the old applications (that ran fine on XP / 2003 Server) because many of them are from 3rd parties and I don't have the sources.

Comment: True, but then you'd know for sure whether it was some weird  32-/16-bit incompatibility issue or something else that has nothing to do with the bitness of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Mike A - I have discovered that syntax 'print /d:{lpt?} {filename}' is not working on Win2008,  not from within a 16bit app OR from the command line.  This syntax has been supported for years and we run it in 10 Win2003 servers.  Might there be a configuration setting in Win2008 that would make it syntax compatible with previous versions of Windows?  BTW, here is Microsoft Tech Bulletin that was updated April 2012 that list the syntax as being compatible with Win2008... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731623.